# Delete all gmail promotions in gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, http-status-code-404, gmail-api

I'm trying to delete all emails in my promotions tab with the following code that I found and modified, but I'm getting an error

```
"Response Code: 404. Message: Not Found. (line 4, file "Code")Dismiss"
```

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
function deleteForever(userId) {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("category:social");
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    Gmail.Users.Messages.remove(userId, threads[i].getId());
  }
}
```

Comment: 1.Have you activated gmail api(Advanced Google services)? 2. Is the userid correct? 3. Id should be message id not thread id

Comment: I clicked on Gmail under the resources tab of the Google App script-editing page, I set a variable inside of the function with my email account address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

- Providing `thread` id to delete instead of providing `message` id to a method accepting `message` id.

#### Solution:

- If you want to delete thread by id, use `Threads.remove` instead.

#### Caution:

- ***Using `Threads.remove` immediately and permanently deletes the specified thread. This operation cannot be undone. Prefer `Threads.trash` instead***

#### Snippet:

```
Gmail.Users.Threads.remove("me", threads[i].getId()); //☠️Permanently and irrevocably deletes the thread☠️
```

#### References:

- [Threads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads)

Answer (score 0):

Credits from https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/0f455239490e5342fa49

Clique na categoria e aparecerá o nome no campo de pesquisa. Neste exemplo aqui é Promoções.

```
function batchDeleteEmail() {
  var batchSize = 100 // Process up to 100 threads at once
  // If you need to add time conditions, you can use d(day) and h(hours) instead.
  // [category:] can be replace [label:].
  var threads = GmailApp.search('category:promotions');
  console.log('batch size is: ' + threads.length);
  for (j = 0; j < threads.length; j+=batchSize) {
    console.log('removing batch: ' + j);
    GmailApp.moveThreadsToTrash(threads.slice(j, j+batchSize));
  }
}
```

This code runs 4 times, deleting 400 emails per run. If you want, create a trigger and run it per hour to complete the entire deletion of the desired category.